# C# creating pictureboxes for every item in a list

Tags: c#

So far i have

```
var championNamelist = new List<string>(championName);
var first5Names = championNamelist.Take(5);
var skip5Names = championNamelist.Skip(5);                  

foreach (string name in first5Names)
{
    string getPNG = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.11.1/img/champion/" + png + ".png";
}
```

In the `championNamelist` are all the names found from an XML.

How do i get all the pictures shown on my form ?

Comment: What UI technology are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: Your code won't even compile, the variable *png* is nowhere declared. Did you mean to use *name*? And, what @David said.

Answer (score 0):

if want dynamically create picture box then try

```
PictureBox[] p = new PictureBox[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                p[i] = new PictureBox();
                p[i].ImageLocation = "location";
                p[i].Location = new Point(0,0);
                p[i].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                this.Controls.Add(p[i]);
            }
```